# Triggered Web Job Powershell Deployment script

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-powershell

**I have a powershell script to deploy continues webjob. as shown below**

```
`$Header = @{
'Content-Disposition'='attachment; attachment; filename=Copy.zip'
'Authorization'=$accessToken}

$apiUrl1 = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/MyWebJob" 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl1 -Headers $Header -Method put -InFile "$zipFilesPath\MyWebJob.zip" - 
ContentType 'application/zip'`
```

**I need same kind of script to deploy triggered webjobs.**
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy triggered webjobs, just change the `$apiUrl1` in your script like below.

```
$apiUrl1 = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyWebJob"
```

Reference - [Upload a triggered job as zip](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#upload-a-triggered-job-as-zip)

Comment: thanks can you tell me how to mention CRON Expression or Schedule in above code

Comment: @GauravMoolani You could include a `settings.job` file at the root of your WebJob .zip file, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#ncrontab-expressions).